# Is it possible to print the result of a php script using jQuery, without loading it into a div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

In the past i've used .load() to load data into a specific DIV on the page.

I want to run a PHP script, and pass it some parameters in the query string, then print the result in the page.

It would go someting like this, where I have RESULT OF SCRIPT I want to run the script, and pass it parameters, then print the result.

The script is used elsewhere in the site, and it acceps parameters in the query string, and prints the result.

I don't HAVE to use Javascript if there's a way to do this in PHP? But I don't know of a way to do it with just PHP and be able to pass it parameters as a query string.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rooms))
{
//Run the price script and print result
print "<div id=\"price-result\">";
print *RESULT OF SCRIPT*;
print "</div>"; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, *where the function is called*? mind sharing some code?

Comment: yea by setting the async to false

Comment: @RobertPitt: Why async is handy here?

Comment: @Dan Harris is it correct to say that what you want is a `<script>` block that basically replaces itself with some fetched content?

Comment: Am i missing something here or is it that hard to give the div an id?

Comment: I've updated my question so it makes more sense. I don't need to use Javascript at all if this can be done with just PHP, if that's possible? When i've used the script elsewhere i've used .load on a div, but in this case there will be multiple div's with the same ID, so styling reasons

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that what's desired is a way to do this in the middle of the page:

```
  <div>
    Blah blah content content
    <script src='magic.js'></script>
    Blah blah more content
```

such that the script runs and the result on the page is

```
  <div>
    Blah blah content content
    <div class='wow-I-was-just-loaded-dynamically'>
      Dynamic stuff blah blah
    </div>
    Blah blah more content
```

If that's so, then I think the only way to do it is to have the script do something like this:

```
    document.write("<div id='magic'></div>");
```

and then start the appropriate asynchronous call to load the content:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#magic').load(url, function() { ... });
    }, 5);
```

(I'm not 100% sure that'd need to be done in a timeout; it depends on whether the DOM is properly updated immediately by the `document.write()` call.)

Comment: I *doubt* this isn't what he wants...lets just wait for his response.

Comment: I don't know for sure - the direct answer to the question is, I'm pretty sure, "no".

Comment: You don't need the timeout, an element is available immediately after its HTML has been parsed (or document.written)

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on jquery for everything.  What you are looking for is `document.write()`.  Use `.ajax` to get the content then `document.write()` to output it.  It'll be output immediately after the script tag containing the function call.

Comment: The problem is that the ajax call to fetch the content is (and should be) asynchronous. By the time it completes, the page is likely to be rendered, and `document.write()` would cause it to be obliterated.

Comment: @Pointy.  Whoops, didn't consider that. +1 for your answer although, why not just have the script actually point to php (or whatever) that generates a `document.write` containing the actual content?

Comment: That would work if the script used a synchronous ajax call, but synchronous ajax calls are a pretty bad idea usually - especially in a case like this, where it'd block the progress of the rest of the page. (If that's what's desired, then it's not clear why the server couldn't have just put the content there in the first place!)

Comment: I have a script (php) that prints the final result (a price as a string). I basically need to call the script at numerous points in the page and display the result where it was called

Comment: While everyone still fancies XHTML the `document.write` approach is maybe not the best option either. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Comment: Each time it is called some parameters are passed as part of a query string. So I am passing different variables each time. Just printing the result of the PHP script would work, I don't mind if it's just raw PHP that calls and displays the result each time

Answer (score 0):

You need a placeholder somewhere in the equation.  You can use a selector and the append method to add something to a DOM element.  It can be by ID, class, or tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        ...
        success: function(data) {  $("#some_id").append(data); }
           // OR to append to the body $("body").append(data)
    });
});

<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td id="some_id">Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All depends on where you want it to appear.  You can use .html and .append in combination with any selector you like.